# Is initial save to local drive more resilient than using network drive

Tags: vba, excel, design-patterns

I would like to create 100 different reports - they all need to initially be saved to one location - then they need to be distributed to various locations on our network drive.

An `Excel vba` program is creating the files from an `xlsm` file saved on the network drive.

Which of the following approaches is more resiliant/defensive?

1.Save 100 files to C-Drive of machine running the code - then distribute to 100 different locations on the network drive.
2.Save 100 files to same network location where controlling `xlsm` file is located - then distribute to 100 different locations on the network drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... that depends. How good is your network? =;)-

When faced with this situation, I tend to write local and them move them after the fact. In my experience, this is more reliable and faster.(Assuming you're using a cut/paste action and not a copy/paste action. Copy/paste is terribly slow.)

Now, that said, I would actually prefer to just write directly to the network drive. It's less code, less bugs, less chance for things to go wrong... ***IF*** you have a reliable network.

Comment: ok - so when you say cut/paste as opposed to copy/paste you mean if I use the fileStsemObjects moveFile method (I think one exists!) I should have more stability that if I use CopyFile?

Comment: ..... No. I'm saying `MoveFile` is considerably faster than `CopyFile`. I got slightly off topic.

Comment: (some extra speed is always good - I will do a full test and post back my findings)